# Hive built in fucntion uuid() not working?

Tags: hive, uuid

In my hive, I can see the following built in function:

```
describe FUNCTION extended uuid
uuid() - Returns a universally unique identifier (UUID) string.
The value is returned as a canonical UUID 36-character string.
Example:
  > SELECT uuid();
'0baf1f52-53df-487f-8292-99a03716b688'
  > SELECT uuid();
'36718a53-84f5-45d6-8796-4f79983ad49d'
```

I am trying to generate a uuid for every row in a table:

```
from (select *, uuid() as id from table1) t
insert into table table2
  select a,b,id
insert into table table3
  c,id;
```

Every single row in each table ends up with an identical uuid value. However, if I replace uuid() function with rand() function, every row ends up with a different random id. 
Why is uuid() only generating one value?

I can't use reflect('java.util.UUID','randomUUID') because reflect is blocked by sentry.

Comment: Columns a, b and c are from table1?

Comment: Yes, all the columns are from table1

Answer (score 2):

The `UUID` function was added in [2.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12721), it had a bug unfortunately in that it was [not tagged as non-deterministic](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15233). If you update to 2.2.3 it will work as expected, if that is not an option, you can create your own UUID generator UDF in it's place,

```
@UDFType(deterministic = false)
public class UUIDShim extends UDF {
 private final Text result = new Text();
 public Text evaluate() {
    result.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return result;
 }
}
```